# opening files in async-await functions python

Tags: python, json, async-await, discord.py, pickle

Am using discord.py which requires using async-await functions.
I want to dump and load data using pickle and JSON modules.
but when trying that I get this error

```
AttributeError: __enter__
d:\Users\-------\visual studio projects\------------\main.py:65: RuntimeWarning: 
coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
```

I believe this happened because am opening the file inside and async-await function.
so I tried an alternative way to open the files with async functions with aiofiles:

```
async with aiofiles.open("owners.pkl", mode="rb") as file:
    owner_dict = pickle.load(file)
```

but the problem is that pickle and json does work inside async functions.

Is there any alternative way to open, load, and dump with JSON or pickle inside async-await functions ???

Answer (score 2):

The thing returned by `aiofiles.open` is not a regular file-like object, its operations need to be awaited:

```
async with aiofiles.open("owners.pkl", mode="rb") as file:
    owner_dict = pickle.loads(await file.read())
```

Then again, this doesn't really help all that much since the deserialization will still happen in a blocking way (only reading the file will be async).

---

And a general note: Even if some interface demands an async function, there's no restriction on what happens inside of it. You can just write `async` in front of a normal, blocking function, and it will just work (without the benefits of `async`/`await` of course).

Comment: I did that but I got a new error

_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xef'.

Comment: I'm not getting that error. Are the Python versions of the producing and consuming system identical? You can also try `encoding="bytes"` as an additional argument to `pickle.loads`.

Comment: i Did that also but i got new error ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument